# Set icon for multichoiceitem

Tags: android

I hava an alerDialog which enables the user to select multiple items.(set using the multichoiceitems() method).I want to add an icon for each of these items.Is this possible.

I want a separate icon to be displayed for each of the selectable items.I have the icons stored in a drawable array.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom item renderers for your multichoice list, - instead of using the `AlertDialog.Builder` class - you should create your custom `ListView` with checkbox, icon and text, and put it in a dialog, then pop it up:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(new MyListView());
dialog.show();
```

where

```
class MyListView extends ListView ...
```

is your implementation of the ListView. In it's `adapter` you can inflate a simple `RelativeLayout` with the three fields you need, fill it with the proper data, set checklisteners, and you'll have your multichoice list with icons, ready to be set as a `Dialog`'s contentView.